# Rewrite rule not working correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to apply a rewrite rule to change my urls which currently look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/my-site/en
```

change to:

```
www.my-site.com/en or /es
```

but I want it to be forceful and not allow someone to deliberately type in the latter.
Also

```
www.my-site.com/en/?page=car&category=15
```

change to
`www.my-site.com/en/car/15` (or I can just put the category name instead)
I also have this:

```
www.my-site.com/en/?page=catalogue-item&category=204&id=563
```

which I want to change to:
`www.my-site.com/en/563` (or I can just put in the item name instead)

Here is my htaccess so far:

```
# RewriteOptions inherit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-site.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^$ my-site/ [L,NS,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my-site.com/my\-site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-site.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-site/$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /en/?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /es/?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /en/?page=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/~([^/]+)/(.*)$ my-site/$1 [L,NS]

</IfModule>
```

I thank you in advance and hope someone could point out my problem, thank you again.

Comment: "I want it to be forceful and not allow someone to deliberately type in the latter." ??? So, users should be redirected to the new URL, but they can't type it in?! Have you already changed the URL structure in your application?

Comment: These Url requirements are not a rewrite rules issue. It is the application code, that will force, and interpret, the chosen Url format.

Comment: @w3dk I mean I do not want my browser to allow my url to have my-site.com/my-site/ to appear just like I am forcing my site to have www. I want to be able to automatically redirect to my desired url.

Comment: @IgorGreg could you please clarify for me what I can do to fix this issue because I do not seem to understand you, I look forward to your reply.